# UIButton not calling event in imageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton

I have `imageview` in which I am adding `UIButton` it shows button when I click on button it does not call the action of the button. Here is the code I am using I have also set the `imageView.userInteraction=enabled` but still it is not calling the action.

```
UIImageView*myImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75,10,200,150)];


myImageView.image=thumbnail;

myImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;


[scrollView addSubview:myImageView];

UIButton*playButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,128,128)];

//[playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playIconPlay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[playButton.buttonType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

scrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
myImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[playButton setTitle:@"Play Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


myImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

[myImageView addSubview:playButton];
```

Comment: add this line [myImageView bringSubviewToFront: playButton]; and then try..

Comment: not working this also

Comment: imageView i am using as backgruond  which is large that is why i am using button

Comment: @QueenSolutions:Initialize the button with buttontype and then set frame. No need to set userInteractionEnabled for imageView.

Comment: if your imageview is not on front, then how can a touch event be passed to it?? bring your imageview to front or atleast play button to front

Comment: @QueenSolutions: If you add any TapGesture in ImageView remove it. Then dont set userInteractionEnabled:YES to imageview. Then use add your button like my ans posted in this wall.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a UIImageView and and UIButton in a UIView, hope it will help for you.

```
UIView* view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(75, 10, 200, 150)];

UIImageView*myImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,150)];


myImageView.image=thumbnail;


[view addSubview:myImageView];

[scrollView addSubview:view];

UIButton*playButton=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,128,128)];

//[playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playIconPlay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[playButton.buttonType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[playButton setTitle:@"Play Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


myImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

[view addSubview:playButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton*playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Try this.. It will work Perfectly..

```
[playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playIconPlay.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[playButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,128,128)];

[playButton setTitle:@"Play Click" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[playButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


[scrollView addSubview:playButton];
[scrollView bringSubviewToFront:playButton];
```

Comment: scroolView check the naming ?

Comment: @Palmyra:See above queen solution using scrollView.

Comment: @TaminlKing:[scrollView addSubview:playButton];
[scroolView bringSubviewToFront:playButton];
check the naming this two line are different

Answer (score 0):

Before adding your Button as subview, please set the `exclusiveTouch` property to `YES`.

```
playButton.exclusiveTouch = YES
[myImageView addSubview:playButton];
```

Hope it Will help you.... enjoy coding..!!!